# Creating TextViews in Android with an array

Tags: java, android

Alright, I'm trying to create textviews dynamically with strings i have in an array. Everything works right now besides when i create the textviews instead of them going down they each stay on the same line and run off the screen. I want each textview i create under the next. Code Below works just need it to create under the next instead all on one line.

```
public void GenList(){
    DataBase entry = new DataBase(this);
    entry.open();
    String data = entry.getData();
    int datanumber = entry.FindShit();
    if(datanumber == 0 || datanumber == 1){
        setContentView(R.layout.nowordlist);
    }else{

    int length = entry.results.length;
    View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.sayLinear);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        TextView value = new TextView(this);
        value.setText(entry.results[i]);
        value.setId(i);
        value.setTextSize(50);
        value.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(value);

    }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the orientation of the LinearLayout (`R.id.sayLinear`) you're adding the TextViews to. By default the orientation is set to 'horizontal', which will make the TextViews appear next to each other on a single line. Try changing it to 'vertical':

```
<LinearLayout
    <!-- other attributes -->
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: Thanks alot, been stuck on this for a while!